# duda sobre el gestor de versiones GIT en un proyecto elaborado en un par de máquinas a la vez

Tags: git, github

estoy aprendiendo a visionar mis proyectos con git, y me ha surgido una duda que no he podido resolver, acudo a este medio, espero poder obtener ayuda. Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en el cual el avance lo hago en dos máquinas distintas, el problema que surge con esto es que cuando avanzo en una máquina (pongamos la etiqueta A), guardo y agrego mis cambios al repositorio remoto (github) y más tarde deseo seguir trabajando en el otro equipo (equipo B), los cambios hechos en el equipo A no se ven reflejados en el equipo B, mi pregunta es, ¿hay alguna forma de actualizar los cambios que se hicieron en el equipo A en el equipo B, sin tener que realizar la clonación de nuevo de todo repositorio en ésta última?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para bajar los cambios que has añadido a tu repositorio debes usar:

```
git pull
```

El flujo completo sería:

*Máquina A*

```
// Después de hacer algún cambio
 git add archivoModificado.txt
 git commit -m “Descripción de los cambios”
 git push
```

*Maquina B*

```
git pull
// Ya tienes los últimos cambio, puedes seguir editando
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que alguno de las dos personas comiencen a trabajar en sus respectivas computadoras es necesario realizar un

```
git pull
```

Recuerda consultar tambien la documentacion oficial de [Git](https://git-scm.com/docs) si vulves a tener mas dudas